# Basic age display helper in mvc using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to implement a basic age display helper in mvc using c#. I am stuck with my code at the moment and need some help. Can some one please give a quick help.

Thanks

my code

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model.Dob.Value)
```

However this just shows the dob in date time format. 
I am thinking of doing

```
var newDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Model.Dob.Value)
@Html.Display(newDate)
```

but i want to do this as helper, and not repeat this.

Please help poor student....hahaha

Comment: Sure, we can help, but you need to show us what you have so far so that we can build on it :-)

Comment: I have looked at some different codes online. What i am trying to achieve is to get age to display in formats like 20 years old. The helper should be able to calculate the age and display new format

Comment: @RoseC But what you have done so far?? I mean Actual code...

Comment: [define:student](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/student) "any person who **studies**, **investigates**, or **examines thoughtfully**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a helper function, in helpers folder. This will take in your DOB and then you can format it to out put some string.

For example

```
public string (this HtmlHelper helper, DateTime dob){
   //do your formatting
   return result;
}
```

Here is a link to my blog that may be more useful. I used a similar one for my project. [Age display tutorial](http://mvctutorialsandguides.blogspot.co.nz/2013/04/mvc-c-age-display-helper-for-formatting.html)

Cheers.

Comment: Ohh, thanks. This is what i was after. Just tested it works awesome. Thanks Mr. CSharpMVCTutorial ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will create an extension method for DateTime to calculate the number of years old a person is:

```
public static class DateTimeUtil
{
    public static int YearsOld(this DateTime date)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        var difference = now - date;
        return difference.Days / 365;
    }
}
```

It can be called by:

```
Model.Dob.Value.YearsOld()
```